# How to change list items of a combobox onclick of two different radio button

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox, jradiobutton

There is a private member in Page1.java which is combo box

```
     public class Page1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

     private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboMonth;

     public JComboBox getjComboMonth() {
        return jComboMonth;
    }

    public void setjComboMonth(JComboBox jComboMonth) {
        this.jComboMonth = jComboMonth;
    }

     public void showList() {

       jComboMonth.removeAllItems();
       jComboMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"April-June", 
       "July-September", "October-December"}));

    }

    public void showList1() {
        System.out.println("Inside showlist1 method");//for testing


       jComboMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"April-June",
        "July-September", "October-December", "January-February"}));         



    }

      }
```

AND HERE IS THE CODE IN scrollpane.java WHERE IS TO RADIO BUTTONS AND i WANT TO POPULATE TWO DIFFERENT LISTS IN A SAME COMBOBOX WHICH IS RESIDE IN Page1.java, BY CLICKING THOSE TWO DIFFERENT RADIO BUTTON

```
      public class scrollPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioAnnual;
      private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioQuarter;
      private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup3;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup4;



      public scrollPane() {
        initComponents();

    }



      private void jRadioAnnualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        :


        Page1 pg1 = new Page1();
        pg1.showList();




         }                                            

        private void jRadioQuarterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        Page1 pg1 = new Page1();
        pg1.showList1();
        }         


             java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                new scrollPane().setVisible(true);


            }
        });



      }


BUT STILL NOW THE COMBOBOX DOES NOT POPULATE THE LIST :(
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Though this seems an obvious source of the error.. `Page1 pg1 = null;
.. pg1.getjCombo..`

Comment: Sorry it's not working

Comment: It'll probably stay 'not working' until you post an MCVE.  But there is no need to be sorry about it.  It is not a problem for me if you don't solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want somthing like this?
[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        setContentPane(contentPane);

        comboBox = new JComboBox();

        JRadioButton rdbtnRedio = new JRadioButton("redio1");

        JRadioButton rdbtnRedio_1 = new JRadioButton("redio2");
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(26)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(rdbtnRedio_1)
                        .addComponent(rdbtnRedio)
                        .addComponent(comboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 201, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(comboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(28)
                    .addComponent(rdbtnRedio)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(rdbtnRedio_1)
                    .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);

        ButtonGroup Redio = new ButtonGroup();
        Redio.add(rdbtnRedio);
        Redio.add(rdbtnRedio_1);
        rdbtnRedio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                comboBox.removeAllItems();
                comboBox.addItem("1");
                comboBox.addItem("2");

            }
        });
        rdbtnRedio_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                comboBox.removeAllItems();
                comboBox.addItem("a");
                comboBox.addItem("b");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes quite like this but the radio button and the combobox are in the different two classes and what you have done here I want to do just vice-versa i.e click on the button and the combobox itemlists changed. Please help

Comment: You want to change by clicking JRadioButton or a JButton? Also try to create a MCVE and put it in your question for quick answer.

Comment: "click on the button and the combobox itemlists changed"
Above code is doing exactly this.

Comment: YES SIR i CAN UNDERSTAND BUT MY PROBLEM IS---MY RADIO BUTTONS AND THE COMBOBOX ARE IN TWO DIFFERENT CLASSES

Comment: i HAVE ALREADY EDIT MY CODE PLEASE HAVE A LOOK

Comment: Post the code of two classes. your scrollPane class has a lot of error. Post a working code.

Answer (score 0):

From Your Code What I get is, you are calling Page1 pg1 = new Page1(); in both methods. Do not do that. This is creating a new COMBOBOX every time you are clicking the  JRadioButtons.
So call the Page1 class at the beginning of your scrollPane class.
Like this:

```
public class scrollPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioAnnual;
      private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioQuarter;
      private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
      private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
      private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup3;
      private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup4;
      Page1 pg1 = new Page1();



      public scrollPane() {
        initComponents();

    }
...
```

And also remove `Page1 pg1 = new Page1();` from both `private void jRadioAnnualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` class and `private void jRadioQuarterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` class

Like this:

```
 private void jRadioAnnualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        pg1.showList();
         }                                            
        private void jRadioQuarterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        pg1.showList1();
        }
```

See the full Code below. Create two new class like I created below and run.
Page1 class:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Page1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

     private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboMonth;

     public Page1(JPanel parent)
     {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(200, 50, 150, 80);
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
            jComboMonth = new JComboBox();
            contentPane.add(jComboMonth);
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            parent.add(this);
            setVisible(true);
     }

     public JComboBox getjComboMonth() {
        return jComboMonth;
    }

    public void setjComboMonth(JComboBox jComboMonth) {
        this.jComboMonth = jComboMonth;
    }

     public void showList() {

       jComboMonth.removeAllItems();
       jComboMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"April-June", 
       "July-September", "October-December"}));

    }

    public void showList1() {
        System.out.println(jComboMonth.getItemCount());
        jComboMonth.removeAllItems();
        System.out.println(jComboMonth.getItemCount());
        jComboMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"April-June",
        "July-September", "October-December", "January-February"}));         

        System.out.println(jComboMonth.getItemCount());


    }

      }
```

scrollPane Class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class scrollPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioAnnual;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioQuarter;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private Page1 pg1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    scrollPane frame = new scrollPane();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public scrollPane() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        pg1 = new Page1(contentPane);

        jRadioAnnual = new JRadioButton("RadioAnnual");
        jRadioAnnual.setBounds(26, 32, 109, 23);

        jRadioQuarter=new JRadioButton("RadioQuarter");
        jRadioQuarter.setBounds(26, 50, 109, 23);

        buttonGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioAnnual);
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioQuarter);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);




        contentPane.add(jRadioAnnual);
        contentPane.add(jRadioQuarter);


        jRadioAnnual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                jRadioAnnualActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
        jRadioQuarter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                jRadioQuarterActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

    }


      private void jRadioAnnualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


        pg1.showList();
     }                                            

        private void jRadioQuarterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              


        pg1.showList1();
        }
        }
```

Comment: I have changed it as per your instruction but the problem remain same

Comment: I have given the full code. Create a new project in your eclipes/netbeans with this two class and run. This is maximum I can help from the code given by you. The code which you have provided in the Question is incomplete, If you still not able to resolve your issue, create a  MCVE (take help frome [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to create a MCVE ).

Answer (score 0):

[value combobox to radio button]

```js
 private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
              jRadioButton1.setSelected(true);
        }else if (jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex() == 1){
            jRadioButton2.setSelected(true);
```